# What is the measure of the set $\left\{\frac{1}{2}\right\}\cup\left\{\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}\right\}\cup\cdots$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Consider the set $S=\left\{\frac{1}{2}\right\}\cup\left\{\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}\right\}\cup\left\{\frac{1}{8},\frac{3}{8},\frac{5}{8},\frac{7}{8}\right\}\cup\cdots$.

This set can be created by iteratively taking out the midpoints from a set of line segments ([Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIcGV.png)). Firstly one takes out the midpoint of the interval $(0,1)$, leaving two line segments: $\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\cup\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right)$， then takes out the midpoints $\left\{\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4}\right\}$  of this two intervals, leaving line segments: $\left(0,\frac{1}{4}\right)\cup\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right)\cup\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}\right)\cup\left(\frac{3}{4},1\right)$... This process is continued ad infinitum because one just takes out finite points each time.
And after each time the remaining part is a countable uion of intervals so it is a measurable set, e.g. after the nth step there are $2^n$ intervals with the measure $\frac{1}{2^n}$, hence the measure of the set left is always $1$ .The original set $(0,1)$ has the measure $1$, so the measure of $S$ is $1-1=0$.

On other hand, the elements in $S$ can be writen in binary form $S=\left\{0.1_2\right\}\cup\left\{0.01_2,0.11_2\right\}\cup\left\{0.001_2,0.011_2,0.101_2,0.111_2\right\}\cup\cdots$. So $S$ is the set of all the binary number in interval $(0,1)$, that is $S=(0,1)$. So the measure of $S$ is $1$.

So what is the measure of $S$?

---

Update

Why I think $S=(0,1)$ is because one can write $S$ in this form:
$$
S=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}S_n
\\
S_n=\{x|x=(0.a_1\cdots a_{n-1}1)_2=\frac{1}{2^n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k2^{-k},a_k=0\ \mathrm{or}\ 1\}
$$
and I think the infinite binary decimal like $\frac{1}{3}$ is belong to the subset $S_{\infty}$.

Also I want the Lebesgue measure of $S$.

Comment: Under which measure ?

Comment: $S$ is a countable union of finite sets, hence $S$ is countable. So if we're talking about Lebesgue measure, then $S$ has measure zero.

Comment: Concerning your edit. You didn't define a set "$S_\infty$". You have only defined $S_n$ for finite $n$. When you write $S = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_n$, that $\infty$ on top does not mean that $n$ actually takes on the value $\infty$. It is instead a shorthand notation to indicate that there is no top value for $n$. I.e., that every *finite* value is included. It you want to define a set $S_\infty$ and include it in your definition of $S$, you can, but you have to make changes in what you had written before in order to do so.

Comment: To add to what @PaulSinclair wrote, $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}S_n$ consists of all elements that appear in at least one $S_n$. It doesn't contain any elements that are *not* in any of the $S_n$. (Unlike summations of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$, there is no limiting process involved with $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}$.) So $S$ contains only rationals of the form $k/2^n$.

Answer (score 10):

$S$ only contains numbers with *finite* binary expansion. $\frac13$ is not there. The irrational numbers are not there. So the Lebesgue measure is $0$.

Answer (score 8):

Simply, since
$$
S\subset\Bbb Q\;,
$$
calling $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure, you get
$$
0\le\mu(S)\le\mu(\Bbb Q)=0\;.
$$

Answer (score 3):

I have a little difficulty understanding if you are talking about $$S = \left\{\frac12,\frac14,\frac34,\frac18,\frac38, \frac58,\ldots\right\}$$ or about its complement $$\bar S = [0,1] \setminus S$$ or if I have misunderstood completely.

Every element of $S$ is a rational number.  $S$ is therefore a subset of $\Bbb Q$, and must be countable, because $\Bbb Q$ is countable. (Another way to see this is that $S$ is clearly a union of a countable famiyy of finite sets.  Such unions are always countable.)  Therefore, the measure of $S$ is $0$ and the measure of $\bar S$ is 1.

$S$ is *not* the set “of all the binary number in interval”.  It's the set of numbers whose binary expansion *terminates*.  That is important!  It omits $\frac13= 0._201010101\ldots$ for example.  This should be clear: every element of $S$ is a rational number whose denominator is a power of $2$.  The denominator of $\frac13$ is $3$, which is not a power of $2$.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is at where you think $S$ $= (0,1)$. For example, ${\pi \over 5}$ is not a rational number.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb: if you can associate to each element of your set a different natural number, then your set has measure 0.

In your case, associate to each element its non-integer part in binary and translate in decimal. (for example $0.1101_2 \to 1101_2 \to 13$)

Answer (score 1):

Arthur's answer covers it, but another way of looking at it is that you've deleted only an infinite **sequence** of points, i.e. a **countably** infinite set, and thus a set of measure $0.$